# Join 3 different events in correct time order (begin and end)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have to generate a report of some occured events. There are three different types of them.
In the report, there has to be a table with the correct order of all three types of events in the correct order in relation to the other types. Here is an example of the data and the joins / left-joins I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE `jrnl_rueb_ereignisse` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Art` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `MengenNr` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Beginn` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `Ende` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `Gruppe` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `WasserstandProzesspunkt` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ZaehlwertProzesspunkt` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `AnzahlTage` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `WasserstandMax` DOUBLE(22,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Menge` DOUBLE(22,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
);
INSERT INTO jrnl_rueb_ereignisse (`id`, `Art`, `MengenNr`, `Beginn`, `Ende`, `Gruppe`, `WasserstandProzesspunkt`, `ZaehlwertProzesspunkt`, `AnzahlTage`, `WasserstandMax`, `Menge`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1476, '2020-06-01 00:10:07', '2020-06-01 00:17:37', 0, 1871, 0, 1, 1.119, NULL),
    (2, 1, 1476, '2020-06-01 00:50:07', '2020-06-01 00:57:37', 1, 1871, 0, 0, 1.111, NULL),
    (3, 1, 1476, '2020-06-01 01:30:07', '2020-06-01 01:57:37', 2, 1871, 0, 0, 1.132, NULL),
    (4, 1, 1476, '2020-06-01 02:10:07', '2020-06-01 03:57:36', 3, 1871, 0, 0, 1.184, NULL),
    (5, 1, 1476, '2020-06-01 04:10:07', '2020-06-01 04:17:36', 4, 1871, 0, 0, 1.194, NULL),
    (6, 1, 1476, '2020-06-04 21:30:11', '2020-06-04 21:37:42', 5, 1871, 0, 1, 1.172, NULL),
    (7, 1, 1476, '2020-06-04 22:10:11', '2020-06-05 01:37:42', 6, 1871, 0, 1, 1.172, NULL),
    (8, 1, 1476, '2020-06-05 01:50:12', '2020-06-05 01:57:42', 7, 1871, 0, 0, 1.131, NULL),
    (9, 1, 1476, '2020-06-05 02:10:11', '2020-06-05 03:17:41', 8, 1871, 0, 0, 1.135, NULL),
    (10, 1, 1476, '2020-06-05 03:30:12', '2020-06-05 03:37:41', 9, 1871, 0, 0, 1.151, NULL),
    (11, 1, 1476, '2020-06-05 03:50:11', '2020-06-24 22:37:56', 10, 1871, 0, 19, 1.583, NULL),
    (12, 1, 1476, '2020-06-24 22:50:27', '2020-06-24 22:57:56', 11, 1871, 0, 0, 1.016, NULL),
    (13, 1, 1476, '2020-06-24 23:10:27', '2020-06-24 23:17:57', 12, 1871, 0, 0, 1.11, NULL),
    (16, 2, 1492, '2020-06-01 00:10:07', '2020-06-01 00:17:37', 0, 0, 1912, 1, NULL, 34),
    (17, 2, 1492, '2020-06-01 00:50:07', '2020-06-01 00:57:37', 1, 0, 1912, 0, NULL, 13),
    (18, 2, 1492, '2020-06-01 01:30:07', '2020-06-01 01:37:37', 2, 0, 1912, 0, NULL, 15),
    (19, 2, 1492, '2020-06-01 01:50:06', '2020-06-01 01:57:37', 3, 0, 1912, 0, NULL, 14),
    (23, 3, 1508, '2020-06-01 00:11:07', '2020-06-01 00:16:37', 0, 0, 1913, 1, NULL, 14),
    (24, 3, 1508, '2020-06-01 01:31:07', '2020-06-01 01:36:37', 1, 0, 1913, 0, NULL, 7),
    (25, 3, 1508, '2020-06-01 01:40:06', '2020-06-01 01:49:06', 2, 0, 1913, 0, NULL, 13),
    (26, 3, 1508, '2020-06-01 01:50:10', '2020-06-01 01:55:37', 3, 0, 1913, 0, NULL, 6),
    (27, 3, 1508, '2020-06-01 04:12:07', '2020-06-01 04:15:36', 4, 0, 1913, 0, NULL, 11);

SELECT 
    tbl.MengenNr,
    tbl.Beginn,
    tbl.Ende,
    tbl2.MengenNr,
    tbl2.Beginn,
    tbl2.Ende,
    tbl3.MengenNr,
    tbl3.Beginn,
    tbl3.Ende
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM
    jrnl_rueb_ereignisse    
    WHERE Art=1
) tbl
LEFT JOIN jrnl_rueb_ereignisse tbl2
    ON tbl.Beginn <= tbl2.Beginn AND tbl.Ende >= tbl2.Ende AND tbl2.Art=2
LEFT JOIN jrnl_rueb_ereignisse tbl3
    ON tbl.Beginn <= tbl3.Beginn AND tbl.Ende >= tbl3.Ende AND tbl3.Art=3;
    

    +----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | MengenNr | Beginn              | Ende                | MengenNr | Beginn              | Ende                | MengenNr | Beginn              | Ende                |
    +----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 00:10:07 | 2020-06-01 00:17:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 00:10:07 | 2020-06-01 00:17:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 00:11:07 | 2020-06-01 00:16:37 |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:37:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:31:07 | 2020-06-01 01:36:37 |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 01:50:06 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:31:07 | 2020-06-01 01:36:37 |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:37:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:40:06 | 2020-06-01 01:49:06 |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 01:50:06 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:40:06 | 2020-06-01 01:49:06 |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:37:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:50:10 | 2020-06-01 01:55:37 |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 01:50:06 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:50:10 | 2020-06-01 01:55:37 |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 00:50:07 | 2020-06-01 00:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 00:50:07 | 2020-06-01 00:57:37 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 04:10:07 | 2020-06-01 04:17:36 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     1508 | 2020-06-01 04:12:07 | 2020-06-01 04:15:36 |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-01 02:10:07 | 2020-06-01 03:57:36 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-04 21:30:11 | 2020-06-04 21:37:42 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-04 22:10:11 | 2020-06-05 01:37:42 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-05 01:50:12 | 2020-06-05 01:57:42 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-05 02:10:11 | 2020-06-05 03:17:41 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-05 03:30:12 | 2020-06-05 03:37:41 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-05 03:50:11 | 2020-06-24 22:37:56 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-24 22:50:27 | 2020-06-24 22:57:56 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    |     1476 | 2020-06-24 23:10:27 | 2020-06-24 23:17:57 |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |     NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
    +----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=005e038ed67ba3a251add6aefe4558a5

I have problems to get rid of the unwanted rows I got due to the joins ... or is there maybe a better way to merge the data?

I expect someting like that to get:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| MengenNr | Beginn              | Ende                | MengenNr | Beginn              | Ende                | MengenNr | Beginn              | Ende                |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     1476 | 2020-06-01 00:10:07 | 2020-06-01 00:17:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 00:10:07 | 2020-06-01 00:17:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 00:11:07 | 2020-06-01 00:16:37 |
|     1476 | 2020-06-01 00:50:07 | 2020-06-01 00:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 00:50:07 | 2020-06-01 00:57:37 |          |                     |                     |
|     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:37:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:31:07 | 2020-06-01 01:36:37 |
|     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |          |                     |                     |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:40:06 | 2020-06-01 01:49:06 |
|     1476 | 2020-06-01 01:30:07 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1492 | 2020-06-01 01:50:06 | 2020-06-01 01:57:37 |     1508 | 2020-06-01 01:50:10 | 2020-06-01 01:55:37 |
|     1476 | 2020-06-01 02:10:07 | 2020-06-01 03:57:36 |          |                     |                     |          |                     |                     |   
|     1476 | 2020-06-01 04:10:07 | 2020-06-01 04:17:36 |          |                     |                     |     1508 | 2020-06-01 04:12:07 | 2020-06-01 04:15:36 |        
|     1476 | 2020-06-04 21:30:11 | 2020-06-04 21:37:42 |          |                     |                     |          |                     |                     |      
|     1476 | 2020-06-04 22:10:11 | 2020-06-05 01:37:42 |          |                     |                     |          |                     |                     |  
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: In row #5 the begin and end dates don't match. How did you joined those rows?

Comment: Also, it must have taken tremendous effort to misformat the dates, but to what advantage?

Comment: What do you mean by "misformat the dates"? The design of the output in the excel sheet (image) is given as the goal.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the different mengennr numbers

Comment: Hmm this is in this case not importent, you can remove this. This can be used exactly like the "art" to get the 3 types of events. This ist just a primarykey to the whole project, which is in this report no longer needed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What are the crieteria upon which a JOIN is being formed?

Comment: Note that if you omit @username then your correspondent is not notified on any new messages